# Puppet 6 and module puppetlabs/accounts hiera yaml does not fill content

Tags: puppet

I am attempting to define my user accounts as Hashes in Hiera, like this:

```
---
accounts::user:
  jack:
    ensure: present
    bashrc_content: file('accounts/shell/bashrc')
    bash_profile_content: file('accounts/shell/bash_profile')
```

It works fine if I define them in my *.pp files.

Please, find more details about hiera.yaml, manifest and users.yamal on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rmalenko/50fce66076fb94635544f70b1ae195a1)

Why doesn't this work?

P.S. [This question continues to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54871219/puppet-6-and-module-puppetlabs-accounts-does-not-create-user-account-in-hiera-ya/54877763),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you are trying to do is not possible.

I have a few options for you. In Hiera, you could have all of the data other than the call to the `file()` function:

```yaml
---
accounts::user:
  jack:
    locked: false
    comment: Jack Doe
    ensure: present
    groups:
    - admins
    - sudo
    shell: '/bin/bash'
    home_mode: '0700'
    purge_sshkeys: false
    managehome: true
    managevim: false
    sshkeys:
    - ssh-rsa AAAA
    password: '70'
```

And then in your manifest:

```puppet
$defaults = {
  'bashrc_content' => file('accounts/shell/bashrc'),
  'bash_profile_content' => file('accounts/shell/bash_profile'),
}

$user_data = lookup('accounts::user', Hash[String,Hash], 'hash', {})
$user_data.each |$user,$props| {
  accounts::user { $user: * => $props + $defaults }
}
```

Another option is to simply include your file content in the YAML data, i.e.

```
---
accounts::user:
  jack:
    locked: false
    comment: Jack Doe
    ensure: present
    groups:
    - admins
    - sudo
    shell: '/bin/bash'
    home_mode: '0700'
    purge_sshkeys: false
    managehome: true
    managevim: false
    bashrc_content: |
      # If not running interactively, don't do anything
      [ -z "$PS1" ] && return

      if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc   # --> Read /etc/bashrc, if present.
      fi
      ...
    bash_profile_content: ...
    sshkeys:
    - ssh-rsa AAAA
    password: '70'
```

Then you won't need the file function or the files at all.

For more info:

- On [what](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/hiera_interpolation.html) you can interpolate in Hiera data.
- The [splat](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_expressions.html#splat) operator (`*`) and a useful [blog](https://www.devco.net/archives/2016/02/28/the-resource-wrapper-pattern-in-puppet-4.php) on how to use it.
- On [multiline-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines) in YAML.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works well and forces me to learn Puppet :)